# How to receive part of the JWT Token in local storage using vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is how my token information is stored in Local Storage. How to get a part of the token, for example, username.

```js
config: {url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login", method: "post",…}
baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
data: "{\"email\":\"dev@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"21642164-+\"}"
headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*",…}
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: [null]
transformResponse: [null]
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login"
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
data: {,…}
token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9hdXRoXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTYyODY3MjQwNywiZXhwIjoxNjI4NzU4ODA3LCJuYmYiOjE2Mjg2NzI0MDcsImp0aSI6Ikc0RW9XRWl4d244ME5WV3EiLCJzdWIiOjQsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.nKlAufDC6huYls9MlThA4oU88VI6U5qrXGCXTz-ot5E"
token_type: "bearer"
token_validity: 86400
token_validity2: "Clark Robinson"
headers: {cache-control: "no-cache, private", connection: "close", content-type: "application/json",…}
request: {}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

How to get the username correctly.
data: "{"email":"dev@gmail.com"

How can the username be stored separately in Local Storage?
please guide me

I use this code.

// Set accessToken

localStorage.setItem('accessToken', JSON.stringify(response));

// view UserName in localStorage for test

localStorage.setItem("apiData", response.data.token_validity2);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing/Loading Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: FYI `data` is seen twice in your example output. Maybe you are trying to access the wrong object?